# What is the Mellin transform of $s^n \Gamma(s)$?

Tags: calculus

I am looking for the inverse Mellin Transform of $s^n \Gamma(s)$.  I found a table in which it is given as
$$\left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right)^n e^{-x},$$
but I do not know how to interpret the $(x \frac{d}{dx})^n$. Is it the product derivate of a function??
I know it is a silly question but it is bother me that in Mathematics using a imprecise symbols?

Comment: With $n=2$ for example: 
$$x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(e^{-x}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks @ K.defaoite  how to calculate in Mathematica I try to use NestList but not work ??

Comment: I'm not sure, but I am positive someone over at [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) will be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x\frac{d}{dx})^n$ is just a short notation for taking a derivative and multiplying by $x$ $n$ times in a row.